# Distriqt GameServices ANE - Apple Game Center Problem

Tags: actionscript-3, air, game-center, ane, distriqt

I'me developing a game in AS3 AIR and I'me using Distriqt GameServices native extension.

The problem is that I can not sign in to Apple Game Center.

In the [documentation](https://distriqt.github.io/ANE-GameServices/i.Initialise%20the%20Service), it's stated that: *If Google Play Services aren’t available then you won’t be able to use the functionality in this extension.*
And there's a code snippet:

```
var result:int = GoogleApiAvailability.instance.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable();
if (result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    if (GoogleApiAvailability.instance.isUserRecoverableError( result )) {
        GoogleApiAvailability.instance.showErrorDialog( result );
    } else {
        trace( "Google Play Services aren't available on this device" );
    }
} else {
    trace( "Google Play Services are Available" );
    //init here
}
```

That sounds odd to me because Google Play Services are not available on iOS, naturally.

I've tried to skip this step and initialize the service without checking *GoogleApiAvailability*. But I'm getting this message after a successful initialization and then calling *signIn()* method:

*The requested operation could not be completed because local player has not been authenticated.*

That sounds odd too, because this is the authentication method itself!!

I'm almost sure that my setup is correct. And the extension is working fine on Android.
GameServices ANE Version:   5.0.011

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, actually that had nothing to do with the Distriqt GameServices, so sorry.

The message "*The requested operation could not be completed because local player has not been authenticated.*" was coming from iOS meaning the Game Center is not activated on the device.

Switching on Game Center in the device (settings-> gamecenter) solved the issue.